# Is it possible to make a non-nullable column nullable when used in a view? (sql server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, view, mapping

To start off I have two tables, `PersonNames` and `PersonNameVariations`. When a name is searched, it finds the closest name to one of the ones available in `PersonNames` and records it in the `PersonNameVariations` table if it's not already in there.

I am using a stored proc to search the `PersonNames` for a passed in `PersonNameVariation`and return the information on both the `PersonName` found and the `PersonNameVariation` that was compared to it.

Since I am using the Entity Framework, I needed return a complex type in the `Import Function` but for some reason it says my current framework doesn't support it. My last option was to use an `Entity` to return in my stored proc instead.

The result that I needed back is the information on both the `PersonName` that was found and the `PersonNameVariation` that was recorded. Since I cannot return both entities, I created a view `PersonSearchVariationInfo` and added it into my Entity Framework in order to use it as the entity to return.

The problem is that **the search will not always return a `Person Name` match**. It needs to be able to return only the `PersonNameVariation` data in some cases, meaning that all the fields in the `PersonSearchVariationInfo` pertaining to `PersonName` **need to be nullable**.

How can I take my view and make some of the fields nullable? When I do it directly in the Entity Framework I get a mapping error:

> Error 4   Error 3031: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 1202:Non-nullable column myproject_vw_PersonSearchVariationInfo.DateAdded in table myproject_vw_PersonSearchVariationInfo is mapped to a nullable entity property.
>       C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyProject\MyProject.Domain\EntityFramework\MyProjectDBEntities.edmx    1203    15  MyProject.Domain

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: um. gbn gave you an awesome answer days ago.  Does it work for you or not?  If it doesn't, why not?  If it does, please accept his answer.

Comment: I'll have to check what I did. I forgot to update this question after I figured it out. His answer didn't address my situation directly, but I may not have been clear with what I needed. I'll write up something when I get a chance and try clarifying what I had needed.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps.

When do you want it nullable? Here I use NULLIF to force nullability and assume I have empty string. YMMV of course.

The metadata is correct for the nullability of the column in the view too

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Foo (ColNonNull varchar(100) NOT NULL)
GO
INSERT dbo.Foo VALUES (NULL) --fails
GO
INSERT dbo.Foo VALUES ('bar') --works
INSERT dbo.Foo VALUES ('') --works
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.vwFoo
AS
SELECT NULLIF(ColNonNull, '') AS ColNull FROM dbo.Foo
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.vwFoo
GO
SELECT
    COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('dbo.Foo'), 'ColNonNull', 'AllowsNull') AS TableColNullable,
    COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('dbo.vwFoo'), 'ColNull', 'AllowsNull') AS ViewColNullable
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot make a column nullable in a view, if it is non-nullable in the underlying table.

How would you deal with that?? You insert a new row in the view and leave that column NULL, but in the underlying table, you would have to provide a value.... that just won't work.

Comment: I just want to select... I don't want to insert into the view